# C code Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):

Tags: c, arrays, glibc

I got an error from my code, but I'm not sure where to fix it.

Here's the explanation of what my code does:

I'm writing some code that will read an input file and store each line as an object (char type) in an array. The first line of the input file is a number. This number tells me how many lines that I should read and store in the array. Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *fp; 
    char **path;
    int num, i;
    ...
    /*after reading the first line and store the number value in num*/
    path = malloc(num *sizeof(char));
    ...
    free(path);
}
```

After running the code, I get this

```
*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid next size (fast):
```

I have searched around and know this is malloc/free error, but I don't exactly know to fix it. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
path = malloc(num *sizeof(char));
```

This is wrong.  `path` is a pointer to pointer to char, so you need to allocate `num * sizeof(char*)`, not `sizeof(char)`, which will always be 1 (but a pointer is almost certainly not 1 byte).

to initialize a pointer dynamically, always allocate the number of elements desired multiplied by *the size of the type that the pointer points to*.  This pointer points to a `char*`, not a `char`.  The pointers it points to point to `char`s (that's kind of fun to say...)

To simplify:

```
some_ptr *p = malloc(num_elems * sizeof *p);
```

The compiler knows how to deal with `sizeof(*p)` correctly, you're not actually dereferencing a pointer (which would otherwise invoke UB as the pointer is likely uninitialized).

Comment: To easily, and always, comply with the rule in your last paragraph, you should use the idiomatic malloc expression: `ptr = malloc(N * sizeof *ptr)`

Comment: @eq-: Yes, good call.  Thanks, I'll add an example.

Comment: ahh that makes sense now...but I still get the same error... I have "path[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);" in while loop could this cause the problem?

Comment: @user1436057: Please show me how you are reading the string(s) into `buffer`.  The problem may be in the code that you have deemed irrelevant.  Also realize that `free(path)` will not deallocate the elements of `path`, so you have a memory leak.

Comment: @user1436057: Also, is `num` valid?  are you certain that is being read correctly?  is `i` ever greater than `num`, i.e., are you writing past the bounds of the array?  Use your debugger to sanity check these variables.

Comment: so I modified the line: "path = malloc(num *sizeof(char));" to this "path = malloc((num+1) *sizeof(char));" and it's not giving me any error... I updated the main post so you can see how I read the line into buffer

Comment: @user1436057: No, you want `path = malloc(num * sizeof *path)`.  Really, that is correct, adding 1 is still wrong.  Whether or not the error went away is irrelevant; you are invoking undefined behavior by writing past the bounds of the array, so anything could happen.  please post that code in the original question.

Comment: @user1436057: Where is the NULL character being inserted?  Your array could contain anything, try setting it to `{0}` before reading in the string.

Comment: so it is fine when num is like 5, but if num is more than 5 say like 10, it will get me the error.

Comment: @user1436057: It's not "fine", it is just acting differently because you are invoking undefined behavior.  Really, the correct expression to allocate `path` (assuming that `num` is valid and greater than or equal to the number of lines in the file) is `path = malloc(num * sizeof *path)`.  Really, it is. Use it, and then inspect the code where you read in lines and allocate the elements of `path`.

Comment: I modified the code like you mentioned, and it didn't show error when num = 5. Error shows up when num = 10.